# What is the work done in lifting the bucket?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, work, power

> A bucket is tied to a well with a chain 20 meters long to lift water. If the weight of the chain is 2 kg per meter and the weight of the bucket filled with water is 20 kg, what is the work done in lifting the bucket?

How to calculate work done while mass is constantly decreasing while pulling it up, what to assume as mass to use the formula $W = mgh$?

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange, could you please show your working before asking for help in the future?

Comment: Hint:- W=F * S where "*" is the dot product operator. You can assume there is no wheel that the chain rests on, if that's what's confusing you.

Comment: I am thinking about the chain, can't its mass will decrease with lifting. So what "m" of chain should be taken on the math equation (W=mgh ) ??? (i) The total mass of chain or (ii) the average mass of the chain???

Comment: see this for more :- https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/a-bucket-filled-with-water-weighing-20-kg-is-raised-from-a-well-of-depth/

Comment: why was this closed, after his comment, this seems like a perfectly reasonable question

Comment: @RaihanSarker: average mass of the chain. The top of the chain gains very little height, the bottom of the chain the full 20m. Different approach with identical result: the center of gravity of the chain is at -10m so when it's all set and done you have lifted the bucket by 20m and the chain by 10m

Comment: @Hilmar, don't all parts of the chain move the same amount, it's just that the mass of each differential mass element is different as the bottom has less rope under it than the top

Comment: @Hilmar If I try to do this with calculus , such as **dw=(m/L).gx.dx** :and integrate both side with taking limit 0 to L . { "m" is the total mass of chain and L is the height}
then it comes such as the result as same as the taking _average height_ not _average mass._....

Comment: not OP here, but that's because the average height= exact distance moved by COM